# XPath match assertion: using a dot

Tags: regex, xpath, soapui

I am using XPath Match in SoapUI assertions to validate my XML response. I am stuck with regular expression - unable to validate this tag:

```
<bookValue>0.00</bookValue>
```

My XPath matches looks like this:

```
matches(//bookValue, "^[0-9.]$")
```

But it always return me "false". Maybe there is some problem with dot symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. Try below instead

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Note that using dot inside square brackets is not good for your case as `[0-9.]` will match either digit or dot and adding `+` as `[0-9.]+` might match something like `...1.2.3.4.` which I guess is not what you want

P.S. As @Michael Kay correctly noticed: dot inside square brackets matches only dot (`.`) while outside it means *any character*. If you want to match dot character outside square brackets you need to use back-slash as escape symbol (`\.`)

Comment: Dot outside square brackets matches any character. Dot inside square brackets matches only dot.

Comment: Yeah. Correct. Updated appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression matches any string that contains a single character which must be either a digit or a dot. Your mistake is not allowing repetition: it should be `"^[0-9.]+$"`.

(Note, "." within square brackets matches ".", it isn't a wildcard).

But note, a better way to validate the value would be `X castable as xs:decimal`. That, for example, disallows having several decimal points.